# Syntax error on a Specific Element in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, syntax, syntax-error

I have this syntax error for exactly 1 line of code. The other don't seem to be having the problem. I am inputting from an excell file to the elements. therefore, the first cell seems to be working. The syntax error occurs at the 3rd time when searching for the element.

Tried multiple other ways to change the finding the element type. instead of driver.find_element_by_id("###") i tried driver.find element(BY.ID("####")

My Code:

```py
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(sheet[("A"+ str(2))].value)
driver.find_element_by_id("day").send_keys(sheet[("B"+ str(2))].value)
driver.find_element_by_id("month").send_keys(sheet[("C"+ str(2))].value)
driver.find_element_by_id("year").send_keys(str("1997")

driver.find_element_by_id("hrs").send_keys(sheet[("E"+ str(2))].value)*
```

Output:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("hrs").send_keys(sheet[("E"+ str(2))].value)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_id("year").send_keys(str("1997")
```

This line is missing a closing parentheses.